# How to remove space between widgets in Column or Row in flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout

There is a gap between the two elements , how to eliminate them?
sample code and effect screenshots are as follows ：

[image: code]

[image: effect screenshots]

code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red, // Color(0xFF275FF0),

          child: Column(
            // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
])))
}
```

[image: screenshots3]

Comment: Your `Column` has no spaces between `Container`s. It is the `Container` which is too large for you due to its internal height or paddings or margins. Maybe because of their children sizes. I can't know from your code

Comment: This code is a very simple stack of several elements, without additional settings for the size.

Comment: just like: `Container(
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),`

Comment: The outermost container has a background color, but the background color between the child elements leaks about half a pixel

Answer (score 1):

I did not notice those pixels before. To avoid that you should use `ListView` instead of `Column`.

Here is an example code with a similar code than yours.

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I also use `ColoredBox` as it is more optimized and specific than `Container`

Comment: Yep,  `ListView` is correct, but `Flex` and its subclasses (`Row`,`Column`) have the above problems

Comment: I am not sure how to solve it at the `Flex` classes